# Process an incoming mail

Tags: email, hosting, sendmail, mail-server

I have an email account provided my web hosting service (1and1.fr).
I would like to do a filter that automatically filters my incoming emails (24/7) :

```
IF (SUBJECT=="MySubject1") THEN 
{ 
  SEND A NEW EMAIL to the sender with subject="Bonjour", text="Lorem Ipsum...."
}
```

What service / language / tool to use in order to do this ?

Online service?

(PS: the features provided by the webmail don't provide such advanced "filters")

Thanks in advance

Comment: So it's a webmail account, not an account you setup on your server with Postfix &co., right?

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo : yes webmail (but can also work in pop3 and imap i think)... by the way i have never set up  a mail service (Postfix? Sendmail)